# Is it possible to populate a column with a sum of other columns in that same list item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-views

I would like to have something like this, where AnnualSales is automatically populated with the sum of the four quarter sales figures:

```
Q1Sales     Q2Sales     Q3Sales     Q4Sales    AnnualSales
-------     -------     -------     -------    -----------
 123.12      234.23      345.34      456.45    =sum(Q1Sales, Q2Sales, Q3Sales, Q4Sales)
```

Is this possible with OOTB functionality, or must I find another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you need to use a calculated column. The settings is like the screenshot below. In my test list, it works properly.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this screenshot!

I'd made the column a Number, not noticing the Calculated column type.

This now works exactly as I want it to!

Thanks again.

Comment: @user3761 Glad to be help. You can mark it as answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using a calculated column. You can either use the addition operator (+) or the SUM function. Please refer to [this Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly!

Unfortunately, I'm not seeing the result of the calculation.

I stripped it back to 'Default value: Calculated Value'  '=SUM(1,2,3,4,5)' but the column remains unpopulated.

Could you tell me whether I need to do something else to get it to automatically calculate and display the value, please?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your list and the calculated column settings.

Comment: Another item to remember that the calculated values are only updated when an Item changes. So, try updating the list item and see it that populated the calculated column.

Comment: Thank you for help and questions last night. I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: If it helped you please consider up voting the post and/or mark as answer.